# How do I plot a standard histogram data to a polar histogram using Python and pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, polar-coordinates

I have a list of angles in degrees. I want to display a polar histogram in which the [0°, 360°) range of values is subdivided into equal bins, and display how many values in the angles list fall into each bin. I get histogram data using the following code (and I've checked it is correct):

```
bins_number = 8 # the [0, 360) interval will be subdivided into this number of equal bins
bins = np.linspace(0.0, 360.0, bins_number + 1)
n, _, _ = plt.hist(angles, bins)
```

Now, I've tried to plot this data into a polar histogram using the following code:

```
plt.clf()
width = 2 * np.pi / bins_number
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='polar')
bars = ax.bar(bins[:bins_number], n, width=width, bottom=0.0)
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_alpha(0.5)
plt.show()
```

but what I get is shown in this image:
[image]

As you can see, bars are not placed at the correct angle, and some of them overlap each other, while they should be all contiguous without overlapping.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try and use [radians](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html), multiply by 2pi and divide by 360°.

Answer (score 3):

As in the comment, using radians instead of degrees:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_numbers = 100
bins_number = 8  # the [0, 360) interval will be subdivided into this
# number of equal bins
bins = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, bins_number + 1)
angles = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(n_numbers)
n, _, _ = plt.hist(angles, bins)

plt.clf()
width = 2 * np.pi / bins_number
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='polar')
bars = ax.bar(bins[:bins_number], n, width=width, bottom=0.0)
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_alpha(0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here were are only plotting centres of bins versus the number of occurrence of the angles in each bin

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

degrees = np.random.randint(0, 360, size=200)
radians = np.deg2rad(degrees)

bin_size = 20
a , b=np.histogram(degrees, bins=np.arange(0, 360+bin_size, bin_size))
centers = np.deg2rad(np.ediff1d(b)//2 + b[:-1])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.bar(centers, a, width=np.deg2rad(bin_size), bottom=0.0, color='.8', edgecolor='k')
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
plt.show()
```

[image]